# __deepcopy__ object with cyclic references

Tags: python, recursion, copy, deep-copy

```
from copy import deepcopy

class DoubleLinkedListNeedsDeepCopy:
    def __init__(self, val, tail=None):
        self.val = val
        self._next_node = None
        self._tail = tail or self

    def append(self, new_val):
        next_node = type(self)(new_val, self._tail)
        self._next_node = next_node
        return next_node

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        new_copy = type(self)(self.val)
        new_copy._next_node = deepcopy(self._next_node, memo)
        new_copy._tail = deepcopy(self._tail, memo)
        return new_copy

    @property
    def next(self):
        return self._next_node

    @property
    def tail(self):
        return self._tail

    @property
    def is_last(self):
        return self._next_node == None

linked_list = head = DoubleLinkedListNeedsDeepCopy(1)
for i in range(2, 5):
    head = head.append(i)

def print_list(linked_list):
    cur = linked_list
    for i in range(20):
        print(cur.val, end=' ')

        if cur.is_last:
            break
        else:
            cur = cur.next
    print()

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

print_list(linked_list)
linked_list.next.next.val = 5
print_list(linked_list)
list_copy = deepcopy(linked_list)
list_copy.next.next.val = 8
print_list(list_copy)
print_list(linked_list)
```

Expected output is:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 5 4 
1 2 8 4 
1 2 5 4
```

However it fails with `RecursionError` after following a recursive path: `linked_list.next.next.next.tail.next.next.next...`

(that is of course a toy example, I need a complicated tree-like structure to be copied in real-life scenario)

Comment: actually, it turned out, that in this specific case use can even not override `__deepcopy__()` at all - and it works just fine; however, the question of deepcopy-ing object with recursive references is still open

Comment: If you override `__deepcopy__`, it is up to you to decide how to handle it.  You could for instance write a function that walks the list, keeping track of nodes it has already seen, and stops walking when it cycles back around.  If you're asking how to do that, then your question is not so much about deepcopying but more generally about detecting recursion in data structures.

Comment: @BrenBarn I might have missed something, but from [docuemntation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.htm) it seems like one should  instance a new copy of object and `deepcopy` its fields with same `memo` dict that handles "not deepcopying" repetitive (appearing from recursive links) objects. If that is not true and one has to traverse the structure and handle of all of these links by himself, does defining `__deepcopy__()` just implements an interface for copying and no additional magic is happening under the hood of actual `deepcopy()` function other then just calling the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that in most cases (if you don't need to explicitly exclude certain fields from your copy), you can just do `deepcopy(obj)` even if `obj` has self-links or other else nasty properties.

Answer (score 4):

While you've decided to avoid overriding `__deepcopy__` at all, the actual question remains unanswered. I was googling for the solution but didn't find anything, so after some trial-and-error attempts I found the answer and I want to post it here.

The reason why the code you've written fails with the `RecursionError` is the order of execution. `memo` dictionary is updated only after `__deepcopy__` returns. You can check that in the source code of `copy.py`. Here is the most important part of it without pieces, unnecessary for our case:

```
def deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[]):
    ...

    if memo is None:
        memo = {}

    d = id(x)
    y = memo.get(d, _nil)
    if y is not _nil:
        return y

    ...

    copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
    if copier:
        y = copier(memo)

    ...

    # If is its own copy, don't memoize.
    if y is not x:
        memo[d] = y
        _keep_alive(x, memo) # Make sure x lives at least as long as d
    return y
```

So, our problem is that `memo` is not updated in `__deepcopy__` before it calls another `__deepcopy__` with the same argument. Knowing that, it's easy to fix your code with the single line of code:

```
def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
    new_copy = type(self)(self.val)

    memo[id(self)] = new_copy  # THIS LINE: update memo before re-entering deep-copy machinery

    new_copy._next_node = deepcopy(self._next_node, memo)
    new_copy._tail = deepcopy(self._tail, memo)
    return new_copy
```